# java firebase HashMap not showing as object field

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I'm saving an object on firebase, it shows correctly all the field except for the HashMap field, why? I need to save it and I need to save it as object field, can't put it somewhere else.

MyTrade class:

```
HashMap<Float, ArrayList<String>> sells;

    public MyTrade() {
        this.sells = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

the method I use to create the object and put it on firebase:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(URL).getReference().child(coinname.getText().toString()).child("Open Trades");
                            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    //set code to retrive data and replace layout
                                    trade = new MyTrade();
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child("Trade" + tradekey).setValue(trade);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddTrade.this, Main.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    //set code to show an error
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
```

When I create the object MyTrade, it initialize correctly the hashmap, it gives no error when I put it on firebase, it just doesn't show on it and when I try to fetch it it tells me it's null so it gives me null object reference.

Comment: You've got two identical constructors in your `MyTrade` class, which shouldn't compile. Are you sure it does? If so, can you include the outer class definition (`public class MyTrade...`).

Comment: @AlexMamo it literally does not give errors, it compiles, but on firebase the hashmap is not shown as a field of the class, it simply is not there and if I try to call the getSells it says that it is null, like if it were not initialized

Comment: @HenryTwist yeah my bad, I removed all the useless things from the code to let you understand

Comment: Does `MyTrade.sells` have public access? Firebase needs public getters to read from.

Comment: @HenryTwist yep for sure, it has public getter and setter

Comment: Maybe include everything we need in the question, otherwise it's very hard to debug and impossible to reproduce. Also include the code you're using to read the value again (or are you checking in the console?) etc.